# An issue with Kiwi TCMS

Tags: python-3.x, testing, xml-rpc, kiwi-tcms

I am trying to use Kiwi TCMS RPC API ([project page](http://kiwitcms.org)) with the newest version installed (3.49) and it fails miserably as below even though I follow the [API documentation](http://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/index.html). I wonder if there is someone that could point me in the right direction.

```
  File "api_test.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(testplan.author)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tcms_api/base.py", line 63, in getter
    self._fetch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tcms_api/mutable.py", line 273, in _fetch
    inject = self._server.TestPlan.get(self.id)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1098, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1432, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tcms_api/xmlrpc.py", line 79, in request
    except http.client.RemoteDisconnected:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RemoteDisconnected'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the reason was a misalignment between the Python library to call Kiwi TCMS (tcms-api) and Kiwi itself. Updating both; to version 1.50 and 1.51 respectively helped resolve the issue.