# How to suppress code inspection in PyCharm?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, code-inspection

Throughout my code I have numerous places where I want to disable PyCharm code inspection for this one instance. How to do it in code instead of in IDE as answer to [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787218/dismiss-pycharm-code-inspection-warning-for-particular-line-of-code) suggests?

Comment: Do you [always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009778/what-does-underscore-in-a-number-mean) post a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440063/an-issue-with-kiwi-tcms) then immediately [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099857/numpy-std-on-memmapped-ndarray-fails-with-memoryerror) it yourself and [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54314661/how-to-avoid-line-continuations-in-python-imports) as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584341/len-throws-with-dict-keyiterator-has-no-len-when-calculating-outgoing-and-in) seconds later??

Comment: No. Just sharing the knowledge which appeared to me to be missing on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dismiss PyCharm code inspection warning for particular line of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787218/dismiss-pycharm-code-inspection-warning-for-particular-line-of-code)

Comment: Not missing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787218/dismiss-pycharm-code-inspection-warning-for-particular-line-of-code which you knew as you edited the question yourself. It has an accepted answer and a comment to it that is the answer you wrote. Not sure that this is fair behavior.

Comment: I can't see any comment of mine under the accepted answer of the question you referenced. Also, even though the answer was accepted it was missing information that I am providing in my answer below about types of inspections that the other answer is missing. What do you see as unfair? What would your recommend to do in such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To suppress PyCharm code inspections for a particular line of code you can use the following construct:

```
# noinspection INSPECTION_NAME
your_line_of_code_to_suppress
```

where the name of the inspection you can take from the [list of inspection names](https://gist.github.com/pylover/7870c235867cf22817ac5b096defb768) (they are pretty descriptive).